# Array of Arrays returning non-sense when running in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

My project has an array made of a request with an array of inputs inside, as it follows:

```
array:8 [▼
  "type_id" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "1"
  ]
  "zip_code" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "88801500"
  ]
  "street_address" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Avenida Getúlio Vargas"
  ]
  "number" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "asdasd"
  ]
  "street_address_2" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "asdasd"
  ]
  "city_id" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "4384"
  ]
  "neighborhood" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Centro"
  ]
  "created_by" => 2
]
```

But when I try to run said array on a foreach to insert it on the database, I get a result that doesnt make sense:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => "1"
]
```

My code:

```
dd($dataEnderecos); //This is for debug purposes, it shows the initial array on this question.
        foreach ($dataEnderecos as $enderecos) {
            dd($enderecos); //This is for debug purposes, it shows the secondary array on this question.
            $enderecoID = $this->address->create($enderecos)->id;
            $this->repository->enderecos()->attach($enderecoID);
        }
```

Comment: And what do you expect?

Comment: You need to use 2 foreach loops since you are using a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @u_mulder i would've expected an array made with all the results separated with index.
Example: DataEndereco("type_id[0]","zip_code[0]")

Comment: @MathiasHillmann, you should add that expected output to your question so that future visitors can quickly and easily see what you were trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using a for loop and using another variable to receive the results of the initial array:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
   $insert = array(
      'type_id'          =>   $dataEnderecos['type_id'][$i],
      //                         ^^^^           ^^^^   ^^^^
      //                Initial Array  Secondary Array Index
   );
}
```